# BeagleBone BLUE: howto start magnetometer on startup

Tags: python, linux, beagleboneblack

I made a small Python3 script that logs the MPU9250 magnetic data. I can start it as a service via

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ sudo systemctl start logdata.service 
debian@beaglebone:~$ sudo systemctl status logdata.service 
● logdata.service - Logging of 6D-Sensor to SD-card
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/logdata.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-09-20 10:32:19 UTC; 16s ago
 Main PID: 1622 (python3)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 1026)
   Memory: 9.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/logdata.service
           └─1622 python3 /var/lib/cloud9/oe8bck/imu.py

Sep 20 10:32:19 beaglebone systemd[1]: Started Logging of 6D-Sensor to SD-card.
```

But  it does not start when it's enabled at boot time:

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ sudo service logdata status
[sudo] password for debian: 
● logdata.service - LSB: log sensor data to SD-card
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/logdata; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2020-09-20 09:40:18 UTC; 1min 38s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 550 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/logdata start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 20 09:40:36 beaglebone logdata[550]: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rcpy-0.5.1-py3.7-linux-armv7l.egg/rcpy/__init__.py:127: UserWarni
Sep 20 09:40:36 beaglebone logdata[550]:   warnings.warn('> Installing signal handlers')
Sep 20 09:40:36 beaglebone logdata[550]: Press Ctrl-C to exit
Sep 20 09:40:36 beaglebone logdata[550]: Bye BeagleBone!
Sep 20 09:40:36 beaglebone logdata[550]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 20 09:40:36 beaglebone logdata[550]:   File "/var/lib/cloud9/oe8bck/imu.py", line 59, in <module>
Sep 20 09:40:36 beaglebone logdata[550]:     data=mpu9250.read()
Sep 20 09:40:36 beaglebone logdata[550]: mpu9250.error: Failed to read magnetometer data
Sep 20 09:40:36 beaglebone logdata[550]: Initiating cleanup...
Sep 20 09:40:36 beaglebone logdata[550]: Done with cleanup
```

Adding a wait state in the script did not help, so I think the daemon was started before the I2C bus is initialized properly. Which service is providing this?

Many thanks in advance for hints!

KR,
Christof

Answer (score 0):

sudo systemctl enable MyService.service

I found this info. online at these addresses for setting up service files on Linux.

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units
- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

So, `sudo systemctl start MyService.service` makes the .service file work during the current session.

And, `sudo systemctl enable MyService.service` makes the .service file work during boot when you reboot or boot your system.

If you need any more info, please ask away.

P.S. I also see you are using /etc/init.d when I use /etc/systemd/system for my file location for starting/booting...